# "Transparent" way of injecting a request/transaction ID into log messages in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm looking for a way to include certain information in my log messages without always having to explicitly add this information to the message itself.

My dream scenario would be that any log message, whether it happens in a controller, a service or a domain class, would include some defined set of information (for example the username of the logged in user). This would optimally happen without the programmer having to worry about it at all, just doing a log.debug( "some message" ) would do this automatically.

The idea is to output the logs in JSON format so the structure for the message above could perhaps look something like this:

```
{ timestamp: "20130130T12:32", message: "some message", user: "steve", request-id: "245692"... }
```

I can create a log4j layout that would format all of this nicely for me but the question is how I put the data in there in the first place.

So my first question is: Is there anything inside Grails that I could use as the "request-id"? The idea behind that is to have a single request ID for any "transaction" that a user initiates. So a log message in the controller would have the same request-id as a log message inside a domain or service class that got invoked as a result.

Second question: Is there a way of "transparently" moving information such as this between layers (controller/service/domain) within a user initiated transaction? If need be, I could generate my own request-id in a controller and there I can get the username and put those two in a map. But how would I transport that map over to any service/domain classes and into their loggers short of passing it as a parameter (which I don't want to do since that would litter the code)?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated and I should note that I'm rather new to Grails, so please be gentle ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a push in the right direction on the #grails IRC channel.

The Log4J (or SLF4J in fact) has something called MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context - http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#mdc) which is essentially a thread local map. By creating a filter and a adding the information I need to the MDC, I am able to include this information in all log messages that are performed in that thread.

The question still remains whether there is such a thing as a "request uuid" or whether I should just generate one with UUID.randomUUID().toString().

Example:

Add a filter to generate and store a `requestId`:

```
def filters = {
   all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
      before = {
         MDC.put 'requestId', UUID.randomUUID().toString()
      }
   }
}
```

In Config, add `%X{requestId}` in the pattern

```
log4j = {
  appenders {
      console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{DATE} %X{requestId} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n')
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't a `Filter` always just touching the `Controller` within a Grails project?

Comment: You're right... technically. The filter comes before the controller yes but it isn't really touching it any more than any of the other layers. The trick is that the filter grabs the _request_ and adds information into the SLF4J MDC for the thread that will handle that request. If you don't do something explicitly to multithread that request, you should always have access to that same MDC, no matter whether you are in the controller, service or domain. Of course, if you do multithreading or call some REST services, you'll have problems.

Comment: ah - thanks! didn't recognize that, but it's really good to know :)